# Faster way of find the closest dates of a vector to an element of another vector

Tags: r, date, closest

I have several time vectors with different sizes and one time vector with secondly sampled.

I was trying to find the closest point to the element $i^{th}$ but this method is insanely slow.

```
    for (i in 1:length(SamplingTime)){
which.min(abs(SamplingTime[i]-rTime1))
}
```

Additionally I would like to know if someone knows how to find the two closest data points to the i element of SamplingTime. My original approach was to convert the posix format to numeric one and using RANN package with:

```
closest <- nn2(data=mytimes, k=2)[[1]]
```

But again it is to slow.

Edit:

```
    SampleTime                        rTime

2018-06-01 00:51:40   UTC    2018-06-01 00:51:37 UTC 
2018-06-01 00:51:41,2 UTC    2018-06-01 00:51:38 UTC 
2018-06-01 00:51:41,4 UTC    2018-06-01 00:51:39 UTC
2018-06-01 00:51:41,5 UTC    2018-06-01 00:51:40 UTC 
2018-06-01 00:51:41,9 UTC    2018-06-01 00:51:41 UTC 
2018-06-01 00:51:43   UTC    2018-06-01 00:51:42 UTC
2018-06-01 00:51:46   UTC    2018-06-01 00:51:43 UTC
2018-06-01 00:51:48   UTC            .
          .                          .
          .
```

The idea is that each time I have to evaluate which are the two values of rTime closer to SampleTime[i]. For instance for SampleTime [3]=2018-06-01 00:51:48 UTC  the closer rTime would be rTime[4]=2018-06-01 00:51:40 UTC  and rTime[5]=2018-06-01 00:51:41 UTC

Comment: Please add a reproducible example and expected output

Comment: Sorry, I was on a hurry. Example and expected output added.

Comment: Regarding "_I was on a hurry_": one of the best way of _not_ receiving a fast answer is to _not_ take your time to include a minimal reproducible example when asking.

Comment: Dear Henrik, I am new in the community so I apologize again. I will try not to commit the same mistake again ;)

Comment: The question asks for solutions to **two** problems, actually. The second one (finding the 2 closest values) is more complex and may require different approaches, as demonstrated by the OP himself. Please, post this problem as a separate question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The posted question contains two questions, actually. The first one asks for a faster method to find the closest value in `rTime` for each value given in `SampleTime`.

The `for` loop of the OP "prints" the indices of the nearest value in `rTime`. (Well, actually the code snippet of the OP returns *nothing* without a `print()` statement or storing the values.)

The code below returns the indices using  a *rolling join to nearest* which is available with the `data.table` package.

```
# reproduce OP's data
SampleTime <- 
  structure(c(1527814300, 1527814301.2, 1527814301.4, 1527814301.5, 
              1527814301.9, 1527814303, 1527814306, 1527814308), 
            class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC")
rTime <- 
  structure(c(1527814297, 1527814298, 1527814299, 1527814300, 1527814301, 
              1527814302, 1527814303), 
            class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC")

library(data.table)
sDT <- data.table(SampleTime)
rDT <- data.table(rTime)
# rolling join to nearest
rDT[sDT, on = .(rTime = SampleTime), roll = "nearest", which = TRUE]
```

> ```
> [1] 4 5 5 5 6 7 7 7
> ```

If the values are required instead of indices:

```
sDT[, rTime := rDT[sDT, on = .(rTime = SampleTime), roll = "nearest", x.rTime]][]
```

> ```
>             SampleTime               rTime
> 1: 2018-06-01 00:51:40 2018-06-01 00:51:40
> 2: 2018-06-01 00:51:41 2018-06-01 00:51:41
> 3: 2018-06-01 00:51:41 2018-06-01 00:51:41
> 4: 2018-06-01 00:51:41 2018-06-01 00:51:41
> 5: 2018-06-01 00:51:41 2018-06-01 00:51:42
> 6: 2018-06-01 00:51:43 2018-06-01 00:51:43
> 7: 2018-06-01 00:51:46 2018-06-01 00:51:43
> 8: 2018-06-01 00:51:48 2018-06-01 00:51:43
> ```

Note, that fractional seconds and time zone information are omitted by default when printing `POSIXct` objects. To show both, a format needs to be specified:

```
sDT[, rTime := rDT[sDT, on = .(rTime = SampleTime), roll = "nearest", x.rTime]][
  , lapply(.SD, format, format = "%F %H:%M:%OS1 %Z")]
```

> ```
>                   SampleTime                     rTime
> 1: 2018-06-01 00:51:40.0 UTC 2018-06-01 00:51:40.0 UTC
> 2: 2018-06-01 00:51:41.2 UTC 2018-06-01 00:51:41.0 UTC
> 3: 2018-06-01 00:51:41.4 UTC 2018-06-01 00:51:41.0 UTC
> 4: 2018-06-01 00:51:41.5 UTC 2018-06-01 00:51:41.0 UTC
> 5: 2018-06-01 00:51:41.9 UTC 2018-06-01 00:51:42.0 UTC
> 6: 2018-06-01 00:51:43.0 UTC 2018-06-01 00:51:43.0 UTC
> 7: 2018-06-01 00:51:46.0 UTC 2018-06-01 00:51:43.0 UTC
> 8: 2018-06-01 00:51:48.0 UTC 2018-06-01 00:51:43.0 UTC
> ```

#### Benchmark

The benchmark compares three different methods

- the `for` loop as used by the OP but modified to return a vector of indices
- a more concise rewrite using `sapply()`, and
- a *rolling join to nearest*

All three return a vector of indices.

The benchmark data consist of 1000 sample times which is a rather small test case.

```
library(data.table)
library(magrittr)
# create benchmark data
n <- 1000L
set.seed(1L)
SampleTime <- lubridate::as_datetime("2018-06-01") + cumsum(rnorm(n, 1)) %>% 
  sort()

rTime <- seq(lubridate::floor_date(min(SampleTime), "min"),
             lubridate::ceiling_date(max(SampleTime), "min"),
             by = "sec")

# perform benchmark
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  loop = {
    idx <- integer(length(SampleTime))
    for (i in 1:length(SampleTime)){
      idx[i] <- (which.min(abs(SampleTime[i] - rTime)))
    }
    idx
  },
  sapply = {
    sapply(
      seq_along(SampleTime), 
      function(i) which.min(abs(SampleTime[i] - rTime))
    )
  },
  roll_join = {
    sDT <- data.table(SampleTime)
    rDT <- data.table(rTime)
    rDT[sDT, on = .(rTime = SampleTime), roll = "nearest", which = TRUE]
  },
  times = 100L
)
```

The rolling join is the fastest method by a factor of 50, even for this rather small benchmark case:

> ```
> Unit: milliseconds
>       expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq        max neval cld
>       loop 51.467338 53.365061 57.174145 54.722276 57.270950 214.442708   100   c
>     sapply 49.833166 51.244187 53.600532 52.424695 55.126666  64.886196   100  b 
>  roll_join  1.093099  1.355139  1.462512  1.408001  1.496544   5.411494   100 a
> ```